# How to configure Application Insight connection string in .net?

Tags: azure-application-insights

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger, the example it said to  `// Configure the Connection String in appsettings.json`

[image]

can you please tell me how to configure it in appsettings.json?
What is the name of the JSON element , I should add in appsettings.json for Connection String in appsettings.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON Element to configure ConnectionString in `appsettings.json` is ***ConnectionStrings***.
WE need to add the key and value.

***My appsettings.json***

```cs
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Your ConnectionString"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

- To read the Connection string in ASP.Net CORE , use the below line of code.

***Way 1:***

```cs
var connString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
```

***Way 2 :***

```cs
var MyConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
var connString = MyConfig.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection");
```

***Output***
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is how you configure Connection String for AppInsights:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "your connection string"
  }
}
```

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core?tabs=netcore6)